# Are 1D arrays faster than 2D arrays due to column major order?

Tags: arrays, fortran

Since Fortran uses column-major order, does it mean that using vectors will be faster than using arrays?

Consider the example below. Will Method 2 be slower than Method 1, as Method 2 accesses `A(ii,1)` and `A(ii,2)` consecutively, which are separated in memory?

```
program main

implicit none
real*8 :: A(10,2)
real*8 :: A1(10),A2(10),B(10)
integer :: ii,jj

do jj=1,2
  do ii=1,10
    A(10,2)=dble(ii)+(jj)
  end do
end do
A1=A(:,1)
A2=A(:,2)

! Method 1
do ii=1,10
  B(ii)=A1(ii)+A2(ii)
end do

! Method 2
do ii=1,10
  B(ii)=A(ii,1)+A(ii,2)
end do

end program main
```

Comment: Have you tried to measure it? What have you found out? There are no *vectors* in Fortran, everything you have shown is an array.

Comment: Equally, `A1(ii)` is not next to `A2(ii)` in memory.  Here there are questions about compilers, hardware and all manner of things.

Comment: OP might be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38353830/how-to-choose-the-best-configuration-of-2d-array-ai-j

Comment: Thanks guys for all your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no difference in those two examples. In both cases you just loop in the consecutive element order. In general `A(1,1)` and `A(1,2)` might be closer to each other in memory than `A1(ii)` and `A2(ii)` but it should not make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Your Method1 and method2 two are equally good.

Consider if the order were reversed...

```
Do ii=1,10
  B(ii)=A(1,ii)+A(2,ii)
end d0
```

There is no way to vectorise that loop (at least not without a gather) as it is not contiguous. It get important when the loop gets large or it is called a lot.

In some sense your method2 makes more sense than method1. Consider this:

```
method4
real :: A(20)
Do ii=1,10
  B(ii) =A(ii) + A(ii+10)
End do
```

You would need to define safelen(10) in an !$OMP, whereas the array form is more likely to auto vectorise.