# How to choose the best configuration of 2D array A(i,j)

Tags: arrays, fortran, gfortran, fortran95

Hopefully you could me explaining this thing. I'm working with Fortran and actually writing my code on CFD topic, and below (just for sake of simplicity and just for example) are short explanations of my case:

1. I should use one 2D array A(i,j) and one 1D array B(i)
2. I have to do 2 times looping, which is the first looping should be 50,000 times and the second one is 5 times (can't be changed).
3. The point number 2 above should be looped 10,000 times.

I write the codes with 2 versions (I called them Prog_A and Prog_B).

The first one is as shown below:

```
PROGRAM PROG_A
 REAL*8, DIMENSION(50000,5):: A
 REAL*8, DIMENSION(50000)::B  
 REAL*8:: TIME1,TIME2
       !Just for initial value
           DO I=1, 50000
              A(I,1)=1.0
              A(I,2)=2.0
              A(I,3)=3.0
              A(I,4)=4.0
              A(I,5)=5.0

              B(I)=I 
           END DO
       !Computing computer's running time (start)
           CALL CPU_TIME(TIME1)
                 DO K=1, 100000
                    DO I=1, 50000             !Array should be computed first for 50,000 elements (can't be changed)
                        DO J=1, 5
                           A(I,J)=A(I,J)+SQRT(B(I))   
                        END DO
                    END DO
                 END DO
       !Computing computer's running time (finish)
           CALL CPU_TIME(TIME2)
             PRINT *, 'Elapsed real time = ', TIME2-TIME1, 'second(s)'
END PROGRAM PROG_A
```

The second one is:

```
PROGRAM PROG_B
 REAL*8, DIMENSION(5,50000):: A
 REAL*8, DIMENSION(50000)::B  
 REAL*8:: TIME1,TIME2
       !Just for initial value
           DO J=1, 50000
              A(1,J)=1.0
              A(2,J)=2.0
              A(3,J)=3.0
              A(4,J)=4.0
              A(5,J)=5.0

              B(J)=J 
           END DO
       !Computing computer's running time (start)
           CALL CPU_TIME(TIME1)
                 DO K=1, 100000
                    DO J=1, 50000             !Array should be computed first for 50,000 elements (can't be changed)
                        DO I=1, 5
                           A(I,J)=A(I,J)+SQRT(B(J))   
                        END DO
                    END DO
                 END DO
       !Computing computer's running time (finish)
           CALL CPU_TIME(TIME2)
             PRINT *, 'Elapsed real time = ', TIME2-TIME1, 'second(s)'
END PROGRAM PROG_B
```

As you can see the different is for the first one I used 2D array A(50000,5) and for the second one I used 2D array A(5,50000).

To my knowledge, since Fortran is based on "column major", so the second case would be faster than the first one, since I performed (in the second one) the looping for the most inner side of array (in this case i=1, ..., 5).

But after compiled on gfortran (with -O3 optimization), I've found that the second one is even much slower than the first one. Here is the result:

1. First case  : elapsed time = 29.187 s
2. Second case : elapsed time = 70.496 s

Could anyone explain me why?

PS: The results of both cases are same for sure.

Comment: Compilers are able to switch order of your loops in many cases.

Comment: I'd guess the compiler unrolls your innermost loop in the first example and then produces efficient vectorized code for the resulting long stride 1 loops.

Comment: @VladimirF: Thank you very much for your answer. Do you mean that the compiler should be able to detect the inefficient loop? Please let me know.

Comment: It could detect it but it is by no means guaranteed.

Comment: @VladimirF: If so, does it mean that the speed of execution of doing looping 2 times i and j would be depending on the numbers of array i and j? So let's say that the compiler on the first case detected that j is small enough compared to i, then it just unrolled the array A to be A(I,1), A(I,2), ..., A(I,5)? Or in other words, the compiler didn't do looping for j at all? 

Actually I've never heard about this case (that looping 2 times could be detected by the numbers of i and j by the compiler, I just guessed).

Thanks

Comment: It is easily detected because you put there 5 as a constant.

Comment: @VladimirF: Oh got it. Yes maybe it's right as you said. Anyway thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A part of the optimization is based on heuristics chosen by the implementation.
You are not going to get a totally deterministic explanation.
When writing programs in languages that allows full array operations like
Fortran, the main point is:
if you can express something as a full array / or vector operation, do it and let the compiler generates the loops for you. That way, the only thing to do is to test with your compiler the most efficient and stick with it.

And remember, it is compiler dependent so it will change with the compiler.
For example, if I take your programs as is (changing the number of k iterations
from 100000 to 10000 to speed it, and averaging 5 runs for each),
this is the timing on my computer with different compilers.
I don't have the time to check with new versions of compiler for you.

```
pgf90 14
A: 5.05 s
B: 0.18 s

gfortran 4.9
A: 1.05 s
B: 4.02 s

ifort 13
A: 2.01 s
B: 1.08 s
```

You can see that where gfortran tells you that B is bad, pgfortran
tells the opposite and totally blows the results from A

Now if I vectorize to let the compiler do the job. Here I modify only A
and eliminate the I loop to have this:

```
DO K=1, 10000
    DO J=1, 5
        A(I,J)=A(I,J)+SQRT(B(I))
    END DO
END DO
```

Then we get this (only program A)

```
pgf90 14: 5.05 s

gfortran 4.9: 5.04

ifort 13: 2.02 s
```

pgfortran and ifort are stable while gfortran is exploiting a trick in the first case, possibly the suggestion of haraldkl (see the factor 5). When we vectorize, the trick is not obvious
gfortran does not perform well. It seems that ifort and pgfortran
simply rewrite the loop for you to have the right ordering.

And if I get smarter and elimite the K-loop too

```
    DO J=1, 5
        A(:,J)=A(:,J)+10000*SQRT(B(:)) ! this seems to be final result
    END DO
```

Then we get this (only program A)

```
pgf90 14: 0.001

gfortran 4.9: 0.001

ifort 13: 0.001 s
```

All the compilers become equivalent because there is almost nothing to optimize.
You see that you can optimize everything be simply using array operations.

---

Update
High Performance Mark pointed out in comment that the compiler might actually skip all the computation if it found that the result is not used, which might happen with some implementations. The results presented in this answer accounted for that possibility, even though I did not mention it in the first place. To prevent the compiler from skipping the code entirely, I printed the sum of all the elements of the result after the computation (after the timing); The result is identical to the 3rd digit after the decimal, which is good enough for a result of ~372684326034.9146 (~10^12). This is enough to ensure that the compiler does the actual computation. I totally forgot to mention it in the answer.

Comment: When run times for loops get that small that easily I always have a nagging suspicion that the compiler has optimised away the entire computation because it spots the result isn't needed and can therefore be omitted entirely.  Have you checked the assembler emitted by the compiler ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thank you for bringing that point on the spot. I did not look at the assembler but I though about that. To force the compiler to not skip the code entirely, I printed the sum of all the elements of the result after the computation; The result is identical to the 3rd digit after the decimal, which is good enough for a result of ~372684326034.9146 (~10^12). I think this is good enough to ensure that the compiler does the computation because the result is send out. I totally forgot to mention it in the answer, I am updating.

Comment: @innoSPG: Thanks for your answers. Actually it was a very great explanation. I also thought like that at first (that it might be caused by the compiler, but I was just not sure before). 

So from my point of view, the conclusion for my question how to choose the better shape of array 2D whether A(50000,5) or A(5,50000) is: 
''Since I must do the looping 50,000 times first before doing looping 5 times, I should choose the configuration A(50000,5), even I perform looping 50,000 times at the outer part, since somehow it's easier by the compiler to vectorize''. Isn't it? 

Thanks again.

Comment: @bob.bob.bob, My pleasure to help. You are absolutely right in saying you should choose the configuration A(50000,5). However do not forget to do more tests if you have access to another compiler as you can see from my testing. Finally, if the answer is good enough for your purpose, do not forget to accept it.

Comment: @innoSPG : Done :)

Comment: Downvotes come and go. Often they are just noice, I have quite couply of them. Very often you get a pity upvote from someone instead and that is net +8, so a good thing for you. But my 2c: 1. Don't beg for accept when there are other (even upvoted) answers for given question. 2. Your test with runtime `0.001` looks like everything was optimized out, nothing useful is being computed. Your conclusion about array operations is clearly wrong.

Comment: @VladimirF, What is wrong about my conclusion? Be specific.

Comment: @VladimirF, I request the comment for the sake of learning. What I have learned from comments in SO is huge compared to what I have learned from answers, including answers to my own questions. When I answer a question, my interest is not limited to help the OP, it is extended get comments about my approach and eventually bring the findings into my own projects. That is why I keep coming back to SO.

Comment: It is not possible for the compiler to optimize array expressions by 4 orders of magnitude faster without  skipping all actual work. I don't believe that test at all. Your response to Mark cannot be correct.

Comment: OK, now I get that, you just eliminated the K loop and multiplied by 10000. But that is a useless cheat. Does not show anything useful. In particular nothing useful about array expressions. You can do that with the original program as well. In my tests the array expression is actually 5x slower than the fast DO loop.

Comment: @VladimirF, is your 5x slower test the same as the OP one or a test on your own problem? And just for clarification: I did not claim and I do not claim to have found the magic to make the program faster. What I said is that "there is no deterministic explanation of the observation of the OP; the observation will depend on the compiler when it comes to optimizing the code". And when there is no possible optimization to do, the result can be the same for all compilers and that was the point of the test without the k loop, and it was crystal clear that I removed it.

Comment: @VladimirF, I was thinking that your comment was about the 0.18s of pgfortran compared to the 4s of gfortran which is a 20 times factor. Now it is up to you to make comment for comments, and declaration as it pleases you (e.g. "But that is a useless cheat"). I don't have the time for that. I comment for the sake of clarity and remarks.

Comment: I am commenting to make you aware of the fact that your answer is highly misleading. I strongly believe Mark was confused in the same way as me. Why is that even there? There is no reason to remove that loop.

Comment: If you want to show the speed of array expreddions you can do that, but in a proper test. And see they are slow in gfortran. You can remove the K loop in the original A version as well, but it is obvious it was added by OP to make the trst run long enough.

Comment: You are still skipping the point that is stated: compilers can have identical performance under some circumstances, and that is written in the answer and it is still there. There has been no claim to explain the observation of the OP or to give a better alternative. There are 3 point in the post; 1) a part of the optimization is based on heuristics. 2) optimization is implementation dependent. 3) Under some circumstances, the result will be similar for different implementations. You can focus on a part of one of these points, it is up to you. But I believe you are smarter that that.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler probably does something like this:

```
    DO K=1, 100000
       DO I=1, 50000
          tmp = sqrt(b(i))
          A(I,1) = A(I,1) + tmp
          A(I,2) = A(I,2) + tmp
          A(I,3) = A(I,3) + tmp
          A(I,4) = A(I,4) + tmp
          A(I,5) = A(I,5) + tmp
       END DO
    END DO
```

In `Prog_A` this gives you a nice access pattern with a stride of 1. If you change the order of the indices as in `Prog_B`, you will get a stride of 5 for this code. The effect of this is machine dependent, but is definitely worse than the simple stride-1 access.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If the compiler could unroll the array automatically (like case 1) which is related to the vectorization technique, is it because of the array j (5) in case 1 too small compared to array i (50,000)? If so, does it mean that the speed of execution of doing looping 2 times i and j would be depending on the numbers of array i and j? Thanks.

Comment: @bob.bob.bob You got it right! The decision to unroll or not will totally depends on the shape of the array, at some point, the compiler will not unroll. Unrolling increases the size of the program, at some point the unrolled loop will not hold in the cache memory, which will cause a cache fault for each iteration of the outer loop, making it worse than not unrolling in most case.